# Create System.Net.WebProxy from string including credentials

Tags: c#, proxy, .net-core

Is there a direct way to create a `System.Net.WebProxy` object from a proxy string that contains the credentials in the form `http://username:password@1.2.3.4:8080`?

By direct I mean without parsing the credentials with some regex and putting them into an [ICredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webproxy.-ctor?view=netcore-2.1#System_Net_WebProxy__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_System_String___System_Net_ICredentials_) object first.

**Edit**

If there is no direct way, I'm also happy with an short and elegant workaround :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately we haven't found a direct way either, but it's possible to reduce the Parsing/Regex stuff to a minimum with the `Uri` Class.

You can create the `WebProxy` with the `new WebProxy(Uri uri)` Constructor and provide the credentials when necessary (Unfortunately the credentials are not added automatically from the `Uri` even though the `uri.UserInfo` contains them).

```
//ProxyString
Uri uri = new Uri("http://username:password@1.2.3.4:8080");

//Create Webproxy
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(uri);
string[] creds = uri.UserInfo.Split(new char[] { ':' }, 2); //,2 is necessesary when ':' is used in the password
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(creds[0], creds[1]);
```

Note: I 'm aware you'd like to have a solution without creating an `ICredentials` class, but this is (in our eyes) the most elegant way to handle this.

Comment: Oh, I just realized I made a typo in my string. Of course it must be colon between username and password and the @ before the address. My bad!

Comment: Oh well, this eases the creation a lot (less regex stuff) :) I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Will test it tomorrow but looks like a very nice solution.